# Proper way to perform a call in assembly x64 by using PUSH and JMP

Tags: assembly, x86-64, shellcode

I am writing a shellcode that performs the syscall `execve("/bin/sh", ,)`. However I can't use assembly instructions that are longer than 2 bytes. Also, it is supposed to work for linux x64.

I'm planning on writing the assembly code and then compile it as shellcode. What I have written so far is:

```
jmp a   
    
b:
pop rdi
push 0x3b
pop rax
push 0
pop rsi
push 0 
pop rdx
syscall

a:

push <address of the first nop>
jmp b

nop
nop
nop
```

My original idea was to use the instruction `call b` in order to save the return address on the stack and pop it into RDI, however `call` is longer than 2 bytes.
For this reason I tried to replace the `call` with a `pop` + `jmp`, but I am having an hard time making it work.

I also tried the instruction: `push [$rsp + 0x8]` but it's longer than 2 bytes as well.

This way I should be able to push the address of the first `nop` in the stack and then pop it into the RDI register.

Note: I am using `nop`s as placeholders for now; I will eventually replace them with "/bin/sh" when implementing the exploit.

Comment: Why do you care about any single instruction being larger than 2 bytes? Also not sure why you even want to do it this way, instead of e.g. creating the `/bin/sh` from code.

Comment: @Jester, I should specify it's an exercise that asks specifically to provide a shellcode as input, having each instruction smaller than 2 Bytes. I can send a single input line, that's why I decided to do it this way.

for example, an input will be something like: "\x.../bin/sh\x00"

Comment: Shouldn't you avoid NULL bytes in your shellcode? You can replace `push 0` `pop rsi` `push 0` `pop rdx` by `xor esi, esi` `xor edx, edx`. Both are 2-byte instructions.

Comment: @SepRoland, you're absolutely right, I kept the NULL values for the sake of simplicity. Also there are no NULL checks in my case, so they don't matter.

Answer (score 3):

I think only `call rel32` (5 bytes) and RIP-relative `lea` (7 bytes) can read the program counter without already having a known-good absolute address somewhere for `call reg` (2 bytes).

You can usually assume an executable stack for your shellcode, otherwise a code-injection attack wouldn't have worked in the first place.  (Or an executable buffer somewhere; if you have a pointer to it in another register you can copy that to RSP with `push rdi` / `pop rsp` (1 byte each) or `xchg rax, rdi` / `xchg rax, rsp` (2 bytes each).  `mov rsp, rdi` would be 3 bytes, although `mov esp, edi` is only 2 if you can assume the buffer is in the low 32 bits of address-space.)

Given that, you can push some machine code for a stub that returns the return address as well as jumping to it:

```
  push  imm8     ; 2 bytes, RSP -= 8 with the bottom byte being useful
  mov al, imm8   ; 2 bytes
  mov ah, imm8   ; 2B
  push ax        ; 2B, does RSP-=2
; push machine code for pop rdi (1B) / jmp rdi (2B)

  call rsp       ; 2B
; RAX now holds RIP, but good luck doing anything with it
;  unless you know where an alignment boundary is 
;  so ADD al, 64 won't wrap, won't need to carry into the higher bits of RAX
```

See [Tips for golfing in x86/x64 machine code](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/132981/tips-for-golfing-in-x86-x64-machine-code#comment389324_132985).  This is obviously disastrous for performance, with stores very near execution leading to self-modifying code pipeline nukes, but that's normally irrelevant for shellcode.

**It would be much easier to construct arbitrary data on the stack using 2-byte pushes** as shown above, and then `push rsp` / `pop rdi` to set up the arg for `execve`.  Instead of embedding a contiguous string into your payload and trying to generate that RIP-relative address in a register.